# What do I link to when embedding Python in C++

Tags: python, c++, visual-c++, python-3.x, python-3.3

What do I need to link to, so that I can use Py_Initilize and Py_SimpleString and stuff in C++?

I am using vs 2012 on windows 7 64 bit. I am compiling to win32(I think) and I have the 32bit python33. I did look through the Python Documentation, but there wasn't anything that I could find about compiling and linking for windows, just for linux.

So how do I link to python?

Do I need to use an external library to embed Python in my C++ application?

I am planning to use a c++ app to be the launcher, to start the python script which calls a different class/module. I am still learning Python, but I know some C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link with **python33.lib** in your python install dir. Also you need to add the **python install dir/include** directory to your path of libs for the `#include <Python.h>` to work.

You need tor read [this](http://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/windows.html) first, also I think you should download the python code and try with the examples there (under PC dir).

Comment: When you say link to python33.dll, you mean in linker>input I put in python33.lib with all the other stuff like the kernal.lib.

Comment: Yes, and you use the include directory?

Comment: I set the additional include directory to Python33/include and what do I set the additional library directories to? libs or Lib? And what .lib file do I put in the Linker>>Input additional dependencies?

Comment: The additional libraries is **libs** dir, try first with python33.lib. Also you should try with the examples in the python help.

Comment: I tried with python33.lib, and it gave me this error:            Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python33_d.lib' D:\Coding and Animation\Workspace\Projects\Embbeding Python In C++\Embbeding Python In C++\LINK Embbeding Python In C++

Comment: '#include "Python.h"\n
\n
using namespace std;\n
\n
int main(){\n
 Py_Initialize();\n
 PyRun_SimpleString("print('testing')");\n
 Py_Finalize();\n
 return 0;\n
}'\nThat is the code

Comment: The problem is that you are using **debug** mode? Try with release.

Comment: Wait, is this linking statically? Or dynamically? Because when I go to the release folder and run the .exe, it works, without having the .dll? Do I still need to redistribute the dll if I send this exe to another computer?

Comment: No, if you used the `python33.lib` is statically.